# filtering for column pairs in SQL

Tags: sql

consider two tables that have the following columns

A

```
1,X
2,Y
3,Z
```

B

```
1,X
1,Y
1,Z
2,X
2,Y
2,Z
3,X
3,Y
3,Z
```

is it possible select rows in B that have column pairs as in A without joining or a third column?

something like

```
select * from B where distinct columns in (select distinct columns from A)
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use exists logic:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2
FROM TableB b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA a WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2);
```